# How can I improve my code for generating a dynamic UI element?

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, reactive

I have a dynamic Shiny UI element, where the user is prompted to select a number (1-4) from a dropdown. Shiny then responds by generating the corresponding number of numericInput() elements that will be used by my program.

The following code works, but it's very long-winded and I imagine there are methods to improve the code to (1) make it more concise, and (2) avoid using if/else statements.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("num", label = h3("Select box"), 
                  choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2, "Choice 3" = 3,
                                 "Choice 4" = 4), 
                  selected = 1),
      uiOutput("input_ui")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$input_ui <- renderUI({
    num <- as.integer(input$num)
    if (num == 1) {
      fluidRow(
        column(6, numericInput("min", h5("Min"), value = 10)))
    } else if (num == 2) {
      fluidRow(
        column(6, numericInput("min", h5("Min"), value = 10)),
        column(6, numericInput("max", h5("Max"), value = 15))
      )
    } else if (num == 3) {
      fluidRow(
        column(6, numericInput("min", h5("Min"), value = 10)),
        column(6, numericInput("max", h5("Max"), value = 15)),
        column(6, numericInput("max", h5("Max"), value = 20))
      )
    } else if (num == 4) {
      fluidRow(
        column(6, numericInput("min", h5("Min"), value = 10)),
        column(6, numericInput("max", h5("Max"), value = 15)),
        column(6, numericInput("max", h5("Max"), value = 20)),
        column(6, numericInput("max", h5("Max"), value = 25))
      )
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is there a better way to write this?

Note that in the above, the values and labels are arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lapply()` to create multiple (similar) UI elements based on choices by the user.

Replace your server with this:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$input_ui <- renderUI({
    req(input$num)
    if (as.numeric(input$num) > 1) {
    lapply(1:(as.numeric(input$num)-1), function(i) {
      numericInput(paste0("max",i), 
                   label=paste0("Max", i),
                   value = (i+2)*5)
    })
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @phalteman is good. An alternative is to remove the server side code completely which is good in its own way.

We write a function which creates a taglist of inputs and use a conditional panel to detect which input is being selected.

```
library(shiny)

multiple_numeric_input <- function(names){
  taglst = tagList()
  for (name in names){
    taglst = tagAppendChild(taglst,column(6,numericInput(name,name,value = 10)))
  }
  return(fluidRow(taglst))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("num", label = h3("Select box"), 
                  choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2, "Choice 3" = 3,
                                 "Choice 4" = 4), 
                  selected = 1),
      conditionalPanel("input.num == 1",
                       multiple_numeric_input(c("min"))),
      conditionalPanel("input.num == 2",
                       multiple_numeric_input(c("min","max"))),
      conditionalPanel("input.num == 3",
                       multiple_numeric_input(c("min","max","min2"))),
      conditionalPanel("input.num == 4",
                       multiple_numeric_input(c("min","max","min2","max2")))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Nice use of a UI-side function to create the inputs. Haven't seen that before, and it seems particularly useful if you have a lot else going on in the server...